# What's the meaning of the 'Out' suffix in "Mental Out" and "Skill Out"?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index, a-certain-scientific-railgun

**What's the meaning of the 'Out' suffix in "[Mental Out](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Mental_Out)" and "[Skill-Out](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Skill-Out)"?**

Comment: Most likely the same meaning as in "Knock-Out", aka. "KO".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the kanji name of the 'mental out' attack,'心理掌握,' a literal translation could be something like 'mind arrangement manipulation grip' ([source](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%BF%83%E7%90%86%E6%8E%8C%E6%8F%A1%20%23kanji)).

So where did the 'out' come from? Presumably, as Nolonar suggested in the comments, it came from the 'out' in 'knock-out,' which would be in line with a fighting theme.

As for the 'out' in 'Skill-out,' it probably has something to do with the fact that the organisation is made up of those 'without' psychic abilities ('out' is in this case like it is in the phrase 'out of,' which signifies a lack of something).